# ObjectInputStream and Binary Data

Tags: java, binary, objectinputstream

I got problems loading my application up with a binary file. I am trying to read from the binary file and inject the data to some HashMaps/ArrayLists in my application.

```
public void loadBinary(String filename) {
    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(input))) {

         // TODO

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

It points to the rather long line

```
try (ObjectInputStream in ... ) {
```

to be where it throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

How they I "open" the stream/fix this issue? Thanks!

EDIT:

More of the error

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2313)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2326)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2797)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at model.Model.loadBinary(Model.java:245)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Could you post what are you doing in the TODO section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen()` [Copyright (c) 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.][quoted under fair-use]:

```
private InputStream getInIfOpen() throws IOException {
    InputStream input = in;
    if (input == null)
        throw new IOException("Stream closed");
        return input;
    }
```

Very strange code. It should throw a `NullPointerException.` Possibly it is overloading `null` to also indicate closure, which is poor practice.

In any case that's the cause of your problem. The resource wasn't found, so `input` was null. You should have checked for that before creating the `ObjectInputStream.`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now. The problem was very silly, nonetheless an issue.

When I gave the method the binary as a file, the path should be "folder/sub-folder/file.bin", but as an InputStream it should just read "/sub-folder/file.bin".

Can anyone elaborate why its structured like this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `InputStream.` It has to do with the correct naming of resources. As you are using `getClass().getResourceAsStream(),` the resource is named relative to the class's package; if you use an absolute path as you did here, it is relative to the root of the CLASSPATH. Nothing to do with `folder` in either case.